# How to Encrypt in Angularjs and Decrypt in Nodejs using CryptoJS

Tags: node.js, angularjs, encryption, cryptojs

I need to `Encrypt` some data in `angularjs` and `Decrypt` in `nodejs`. I've seen this `stackoverflow` answer:

[Angular CryptoJs Encryption Not Decryption in Node JS CryptoJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47466845/angular-cryptojs-encryption-not-decryption-in-node-js-cryptojs)

and tried to use `CryptoJS` in my `angularjs` app this way:

HTML

```
<script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/rollups/aes.js"></script>
<script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/components/enc-base64-min.js"></script>
```

JS

```
app.controller('test', function ($scope) {
   var param = 'abc'
   var encry = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(param, 'key');
   console.log(encry);
});
```

But getting this error:

```
CryptoJS is not defined
```

I'm new in `angularjs` so don't have much idea about how to use different libraries.
An example of `encryption` in `angularjs` and `decryption` in `nodejs` would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to remove the two scripts associated with crypto-js that you already have in the HTML and replace them with:

`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.0.0/crypto-js.min.js"></script>`

I hope this works.